# Rounding bug in variable info from RxSpssData

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I have discovered what I think is a bug in the way MicrosoftR handles metadata from .sav files from SPSS.

Here is a summary of the Variable View:

```
ColumnA: 1 - Yes, 2 - No
ColumnB: 0.33 - Yes, 0.5 - Maybe, 0.66 - No, 0.99 - Why not, 1.00 - Yes, for sure.
ColumnC: A - Yes, B - No
```

My code:

```
library(RevoScaleR)

df <- RxSpssData(
  "RoundingTest.sav", 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
  labelsAsInfo = TRUE, 
  labelsAsLevels = TRUE,
  mapMissingCodes = "none" 
)

test = rxImport(df)
```

The data reads in fine:

```
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC Var0001
1     Yes    0.33     Yes      NA
2      No    0.50     Yes      NA
3     Yes    0.66      No      NA
```

The valueInfoCodes, however, do not:

```
attr(test$ColumnA, ".rxValueInfoCodes") # NULL
attr(test$ColumnB, ".rxValueInfoCodes") # "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
attr(test$ColumnC, ".rxValueInfoCodes") # NULL
```

It seems to be using some sort of floor function on the metadata in the numeric columns before converting them to character strings.

I have tried using `options(scipen = 12)` and `rxOptions(numDigits = 12)` with no success. Using `rxDataStep` instead of `rxImport` doesn't work. I believe the error to be somewhere in the RxSpssData() function.

- Has anyone experienced this with RxSpssData, or any other file type?
- Is there a workaround?
- Is there a formal way to report it to Microsoft if it's a genuine bug?

Thanks!

Also, my session info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

EDIT: Added the sample SAV file to a GitHub repo [here.](https://github.com/olfrost/RxSpssDataBug)

Comment: Can you use haven and do an equivalent process to see what the results are?

Comment: I've used a combination of libraries like `Rz`, `foreign` and `memisc` prior to this. I was hoping to get it working on MicrosoftR for a few reasons, but alas.

Comment: You can - but it's good to confirm the issue is definitely with the microsoft bit

Comment: I've had no issues with other packages, if that's what you're asking

Comment: In fact, I've tried `haven` tonight for the first time and found it to be a nicely put together package. I seem to be getting good results with everything except `RevoScaleR`

Comment: Well that's good(ish)! Glad to see the github repro. Will look-see tomorrow

Comment: Don't they have a bug reporting portal?

Comment: MS don't seem to be accepting bugs for Microsoft R right now, according to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-bugs

Comment: It might be worth posting to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=MicrosoftR as well

Comment: Thanks @BobAlbright, I've posted it to MSDN too.

Comment: How `attr(dat$ColumnB, ".rxValueInfoCodes")` result should look like?

Comment: `"0.33" "0.5" "0.66" "0.99" "1"`